# Find the next available number in a python list

Tags: python

I have a list of integers that represent how many times an item has been used and I need to find the next number in the sequence that has been used the least amount of times (it might not even be in the list)

The amount of items is dynamic, the example uses 9 but that could be. Also, the amount of times it can appear is dynamic too.

`We have X items, all of which are allowed to be used y times`

Example.

We have 9 items, both of which are allowed to be used 2 times but should be used in order.

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]
```

the above should return 3 as the next available item

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

the above should return 6 as the next available item

```py
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

the above should return nothing, as there's no more available

I've already got me a function that's checking if the number appears at the max amount of uses

```py
def is_item_available(item_number: int, uses: int, used_items: List):
    """Check if the item is available.
    Args:
        item_number (int): item number to be checked
        uses (int): number of uses allowed
        used_items (list): list of items currently used in a session
    Returns:
        bool: returns True if used item count is less than the uses number
    """
    return used_items.count(item_number) < uses
```

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: You can define generator function which will yield every time next index or make iterator from `itertools.cycle()` and use `next()`. `l = iter(cycle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])) ; next(l)`

Comment: Can you provide some info about the items? Is it a given list of integers? Are they all seuquencial? Are they always a range (0 to something)?

Comment: Maybe I missing somethong, but why not start from smallest possible to highest possible and count if appears less than allowed, if so return it and done if no continue to next one. If all of them appear at least maximum allowed return nothing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function works, if the numbers are guaranteed to be from 1-9:

```py
def next_item(used_items):
    if (used_items[-1] == 9 and len(used_items) == 18):
        return "nothing"
    elif (used_items[-1] == 9):
        return 1
    else:
        return used_items[-1] + 1
```

Comment: How about cases like `list = [1]*17 + [2]`? Expected answer is 2, but you would return `nothing`

Comment: Also, what is `used_items.length`?

Comment: @SerialLazer yes, this function only works if the numbers are from 1-9 and are increased every time by 1.

Comment: I think thats a harsh limitation on the question, anecdotally based on the examples by OP!

Comment: Even in that case, its wrong because the OP asks `the least used item`. How about `list=[1-9]*3`? Its expected to return nothing, but you would return 1!

Comment: Yes, I think the first clause should be: `if len(used_items) >= 18:`. Also the brackets round the expressions are not needed in python.

Comment: @quamrana Just `if len(used_items) >= 18:` wont be sufficient I guess. How about `list=[1-9]*3 + [1]`

Comment: Why not? The OP states that items can be used a max of two times.

Answer (score 1):

Most optimal solution would be to use a min-heap to store the online data and fetch the top of the heap:

```
import collections, heapq

lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2]

## Counter will maintain the count of each element in the list
counter = collections.Counter(lst)

## We now create a min-heap with (counter.count, list.val) as elements
heap = [(value, key) for key,value in dict(counter).items()]

## Now fetch the top element from the min-heap. By definition, this would correspond to the minimum list.val with minimum count

smallest_element = heapq.nsmallest(1, heap)

## If the list.val is already been used twice, return "None" else return the list.val 
if smallest_element[0] > 1:
  return None
return smallest_element[1]
```

Comment: wouldn't it be `return smallest_element[0][1]` ? as [1] would be out of index.

Comment: @NeilHickman `smallest_element` is just a tuple fetched from the min-heap

Comment: and you can't compare a tuple to an int?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `heap = [(value, key) for key,value in dict(counter).items()]; heapq.heapify(heap)`?

Comment: If I understand your algorithm correctly, it returns the smallest value if it's available, and `None` if the smallest value is not available. But what if the second-smallest value is available? You shouldn't return `None` in that case. In any case, I strongly suggest adding explanations as to how this algorithm is supposed to work.

Comment: Using generic variable names like `key` and `value` is also very confusing, especially since it appears `key` refers to the value in the list and `value` to the number of occurrences of that value. A reader would easily be misled into believing `value` refers to the value in the list.

Comment: @Stef the min-heap is built on counter-values not on the list-values. the `smallest_element` is a tuple, something like `(2, 1)`. Not sure why the answer was marked negative

Comment: I see. I suggest you add explanations to the answer.

Comment: thanks @Stef, I have added the explanations now. Hope it clarifies

Comment: Great! Thanks. There is still one small ambiguity in the explanation as "the minimum list.val with minimum count" might mean several different things. Also, the OP says the max number of allowed occurrences is a parameter, whereas your code hardcodes it at 2. You could encapsulate your code in a function, add a parameter, and replace `if smallest_element[0] > 1:` with `if smallest_element[0] >= parameter:`

Comment: The OP updated that restriction quite recently. Earlier it was hardcoded at 2. Look at the other answers, they assume it even more so :)